# Excel 2010 VBA Runtime 1004' PasteSpecial Method of class failed intermittently?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

The below section of code works majority of the time but occasionally it will throw an error for

`loc.PasteSpecial xlValues`

with

> Runtime 1004' PasteSpecial Method of class failed

I cant get it to regularly fault either so is hampering me tracking down the cause. Error doesn't happen when stepping through the code.

This method of copy and paste special is used a few times through out the macro.

Other answers for this question seem to be different use cases so I'm struggling to find the issue within my code.

```
'extracts the cfc data out to its own table if its there.
If Not IsError(Application.Match("CFC", rng1, 0)) Then
wb2.Sheets("Import").Activate
'reset filter to show all data
If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BK1").AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BK1").AutoFilter Field:=1, 
'filters data based on criteria
Criteria1:=Array("*criteria1*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BK1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array("*CFC*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
'Copys the rows that are visable.
Range("A2:BK" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1) _
    .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Copy


wb2.Sheets("CFC").Select
'reset filter to show all data
If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
 ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If

With Range("a:a") 'find the next available row on sheet data using column A
Set loc = .Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False)
End With
outputrow = loc.Row 'sets the output row
loc.PasteSpecial xlValues
loc.PasteSpecial xlFormats

End If
```

Basic fuction is.

- Autofilter data based on Criteria on the main data sheet
- Copy remaining viable rows
- Reset filtering on destination sheet
- Find empty row at bottom of table
- Paste copied rows to the found location.

I've been trying to sort this for a while now so any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only copy the range *immediately* before you paste it (use a variable to store the range to copy).

Comment: Thanks @Rory that seems to have done the trick. Will test with reimporting the data on mass and post the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only copy the range immediately before you paste it (use a variable to store the range to copy). –  Rory

As Rory commented. It was not placing the copy immediately before the paste that was causing the issues.

The copy code was changed to use a sheet reference variable and placed right before the paste and now the macro works as intended 100% of the time. :)

```
    outputrow = loc.Row 'sets the output row
sh1.Range("A2:BK" & sh1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1) _
    .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Copy
loc.PasteSpecial xlValues
loc.PasteSpecial xlFormats
```